# Getting SessionNotCreatedError with protractor and Angular 8

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver, angular8

Project is build in Angular 8. In order to serve responses to the APIs, I have implemented a mock server. My package.json has the following scripts:

```
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"mock": "node lib/stub-server",
"start": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm:mock\" \"ng serve\"",
"validate-pipeline-quality": "node validate-pipeline-quality.js",
"build": "ng build --prod --output-hashing=none && node build-element.js",
"test": "ng test --watch=false",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "concurrently --kill-others --success \"first\" \"ng e2e\" \"npm:mock\""
```

},

Recently, I am facing the error while running npm run e2e. Below is the error:

```
FVFXR3EBHV2H:communication-preference-public smukher$ npm run e2e

> communication-preference-public@1.1.0 e2e /Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public
> concurrently --kill-others --success "first" "ng e2e" "npm:mock"

[mock] 
[mock] > communication-preference-public@1.1.0 mock /Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public
[mock] > node lib/stub-server
[mock] 
[mock] /Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/lib/stub-server/../../test/stub-server
[mock] Mock Server is listening at 8080
[0] [10:38:03] I/config_source - curl -o/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
[0] [10:38:06] I/update - chromedriver: file exists /Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_80.0.3987.16.zip
[0] [10:38:06] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_80.0.3987.16.zip
[0] [10:38:06] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_80.0.3987.16
[0] [10:38:06] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_80.0.3987.16 up to date
[0] ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:4200/webpack-dev-server/
[0] ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
[0] ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html
[0] 
[0] chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 42.8 kB [initial] [rendered]
[0] chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 268 kB [initial] [rendered]
[0] chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
[0] chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 13.7 kB [entry] [rendered]
[0] chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 10.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
[0] chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 4.58 MB [initial] [rendered]
[0] Date: 2020-02-05T09:38:15.981Z - Hash: de103d383b4a486e03cd - Time: 7446ms
[0] ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
[0] ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
[0] [10:38:16] I/launcher - Running 2 instances of WebDriver
[0] [10:38:17] I/testLogger - 
[0] ------------------------------------
[0] 
[0] [10:38:17] I/testLogger - [chrome #01] PID: 6939
[0] [chrome #01] Specs: /Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/e2e/src/app.component.ispec.ts
[0] [chrome #01] 
[0] [chrome #01] [10:38:16] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[0] [chrome #01] 
[0] [chrome #01] /Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546
[0] [chrome #01]         throw new ctor(message);
[0] [chrome #01]               ^
[0] [chrome #01] SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80
[0] [chrome #01]   (Driver info: chromedriver=80.0.3987.16 (320f6526c1632ad4f205ebce69b99a062ed78647-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#185}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.6 x86_64)
[0] [chrome #01]     at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
[0] [chrome #01]     at parseHttpResponse (/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
[0] [chrome #01]     at doSend.then.response (/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
[0] [chrome #01]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[0] [chrome #01] From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
[0] [chrome #01]     at Function.createSession (/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
[0] [chrome #01]     at Function.createSession (/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
[0] [chrome #01]     at Direct.getNewDriver (/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:77:33)
[0] [chrome #01]     at Runner.createBrowser (/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
[0] [chrome #01]     at q.then.then (/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
[0] [chrome #01]     at _fulfilled (/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
[0] [chrome #01]     at /Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30
[0] [chrome #01]     at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
[0] [chrome #01]     at /Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
[0] [chrome #01]     at runSingle (/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
[0] 
[0] [10:38:17] I/testLogger - 
[0] 
[0] [10:38:17] E/launcher - Runner process exited unexpectedly with error code: 1
[0] [10:38:17] I/launcher - 1 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[0] [10:38:17] I/testLogger - 
[0] ------------------------------------
[0] 
[0] [10:38:17] I/testLogger - [chrome #11] PID: 6940
[0] [chrome #11] Specs: /Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/e2e/src/app.component.ispec.ts
[0] [chrome #11] 
[0] [chrome #11] [10:38:16] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[0] [chrome #11] 
[0] [chrome #11] /Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546
[0] [chrome #11]         throw new ctor(message);
[0] [chrome #11]               ^
[0] [chrome #11] SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80
[0] [chrome #11]   (Driver info: chromedriver=80.0.3987.16 (320f6526c1632ad4f205ebce69b99a062ed78647-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#185}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.6 x86_64)
[0] [chrome #11]     at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
[0] [chrome #11]     at parseHttpResponse (/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
[0] [chrome #11]     at doSend.then.response (/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
[0] [chrome #11]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[0] [chrome #11] From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
[0] [chrome #11]     at Function.createSession (/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
[0] [chrome #11]     at Function.createSession (/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
[0] [chrome #11]     at Direct.getNewDriver (/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:77:33)
[0] [chrome #11]     at Runner.createBrowser (/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
[0] [chrome #11]     at q.then.then (/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
[0] [chrome #11]     at _fulfilled (/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
[0] [chrome #11]     at /Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30
[0] [chrome #11]     at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
[0] [chrome #11]     at /Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
[0] [chrome #11]     at runSingle (/Users/smukher/AEVA/Applications/Frontend/communication-preference-public/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
[0] 
[0] [10:38:17] I/testLogger - 
[0] 
[0] [10:38:17] E/launcher - Runner process exited unexpectedly with error code: 1
[0] [10:38:17] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[0] [10:38:17] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed with exit code: 1
[0] [10:38:17] I/launcher - chrome #11 failed with exit code: 1
[0] [10:38:17] I/launcher - overall: 2 process(es) failed to complete
[0] [10:38:17] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
[0] ng e2e exited with code 1
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
[mock] npm run mock exited with code SIGTERM
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! communication-preference-public@1.1.0 e2e: `concurrently --kill-others --success "first" "ng e2e" "npm:mock"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the communication-preference-public@1.1.0 e2e script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/smukher/.npm/_logs/2020-02-05T09_38_17_200Z-debug.log
```

I have checked the chromedriver version and its up to date.
I have checked the webdriver-manager version in protractor, thats also 12.1.7
I have tried for all the tricks mentioned online. But nothing seemed to help in my case.

Can someone please help me in this?

Thanks

Shaswata Mukherjee

Comment: Same error here, can't update driver up to 79.0.3945.130...

Comment: Hi How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just update your chrome browser version to 80. It will fix the issue.

If it doesn't fix the issue please post your configuration details.

Comment: Revision fcea73228632975e052eb90fcf6cd1752d3b42b4-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#974}. 
OS macOS Version 10.14.6 (Build 18G3020). 
JavaScript V8 8.0.426.26. 
Flash 32.0.0.330 /Users/***/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/PepperFlash/32.0.0.330/PepperFlashPlayer.plugin. 
User Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36
Command Line /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end --enable-audio-service-sandbox

Comment: Google Chrome 80.0.3987.132 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: what's the value for "directConnect": ,? @ShaswataMukherjee
please post your conf.js file content